# computing number of primes with congruence constraint

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Suppose I give you $(a, b, M)$ and ask you to compute the number of primes not exceeding $M$ which are congruent to $b$ mod $a.$ What is the most efficient way of doing it? (without congruence restrictions there is the Meissel-Lehmer algorithm).

Comment: Are you thinking of $a$ fixed, and $M$ large?   Computing via the explicit formula and finding zeros of $L$-functions, would seem a good way to me -- would have complexity about $a M^{1/2+\epsilon}$.

Comment: @Lucia Yes, I am thinking of fixed $a.$ How much precision would be needed for the zeros? And without congruence conditions, is the explicit formula faster (theoretically or practically)than Meissel-Lehmer?